# Celery, zmq, message passing approach for a distributed system

Tags: redis, celery, message-queue, zeromq, distributed-computing

I need to implement a system which does the following:

1. Transfer data to a remote place.
2. Once the data gets transferred fully, start a computation on the remote server.
3. Once the computation is done, fetch the resulting computed data back to the source.
4. A web interface to track/edit the progress of each task.

I am thinking of using:
1. Ruby on Rails for 4)
2. Celery as the distributed solution.
3. Zmq to pass messages across to RoR app and in between the different "categories" of workers within celery described below.

To decouple these components from each other, I'm considering having 3 sets of celery workers, each belonging to a separate category :-
A. 'Sync' workers,
B. 'Render' workers, and
C. 'Fetch' workers.

I wanna use zmq pub sub or broadcast model to pass messages around between these sets of workers and the web app so that they can be synchronised properly. For example B) should only kick in once A) is done. And C) should follow B).

Does this approach sound reasonable or can it be done better using perhaps just zmq or celery alone? Should instead of these I be using the celery back end like redis or amp?

Reasons I wanna use celery is of course data persistence as well as a web interface to monitor the workers.

I'm obviously relatively new to celery, zmq and distributed computation in general so any advice would be welcome.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar for work but it has all been done using rabbitmq and celery.  The way I would approach this is have a celery worker running on the remote server and on the local host.  Have each worker have it's own unique queue and fire off a chain something like
`chain(sync.s(file), compute.s(), sync_back.s()).delay`  have the 2 sync tasks go to the localhost queue and the compute task go into the remote host queue

Comment: If I get you, you mean to say that the sync and fetch tasks should go to the local queue and the compute task go the offshore queue correct? But how do you propose the communication should happen between these queues and the web app as the app needs to display the download upload and computational progress as well as ability to edit them. This is where I was hoping the no frills zmq pub sub would help. Any other ideas on it? Thanks.

Comment: I can't speak to zmq so I'll talk to what I know the queues wouldn't communicate rabbitmq would handle the interaction between the workers and the queues what happens in the chain is when the sync is finished the compute tasks would get put into the "compute" queue and would get picked up on the offshore.  As for monitoring if you just want to see what is done you can monitor the workers and queues to see what is done.  Unsure what you mean by edit them or if this is how you want to watch them.

Comment: Well I intend to have a web app that will show the progress of the running tasks, be it in sync, compute or fetch phases. I also want to have a control over these tasks so as to abort them if needed via the web app. The web app I'm planning is a Rails app so what, if any, approach you suggest I could use to pass messages around between the celery queue and the web app?

Comment: Ahh I see take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flower that should get you going in the right direction.  As for monitoring as lets say you have 100 files and just care when 1 file is done that is easy and flower basically does that.  If you have 1 file and care what percent of that file is done that is a much more difficult problem and would require monitoring in the code most likely writing out to a file or database.